# Angular Service Worker for PWA not registering

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, angular-service-worker

Hi I am new to coding and angular so please bear with me.

I have not been able to get my service worker registered. I have tried both Chrome and Firefox, but I have been mainly using Chrome. I am using localhost to serve, and angular version 15.0.1.

I have also tried these things:

- scope matches start url `"/"`
- installMode set to `"lazy"`
- serviceWorker set to `true` in angular.json
- registrationStrategy set to `"registerImmediately"`

My code is here https://github.com/mmmgluten/so

Any help would be appreciated thank you.